# Dwarves keep dumping seeds in a corner?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

For some reason, the dwarves keep putting a lot of seeds in once specific corner. Is this supposed to happen?

[image: Screenshot showing a long list of seeds, a chair, and the type of floor]

Comment: I was about to say this sounded more of a computer error than a question about the game, but it seems like this is normal. carry on. @null

Comment: @Xenon If you think this is a program error, you haven't played dwarf fortress :-)

Comment: @quarague you're right, I haven't played it. However, I've been a programmer for quite a while, and this is the sort of thing that happens with a glitch. After some research I found that this is indeed part of the game and not an error.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is that there's also a chair there. What's happening is the dwarfs are eating at that location, which *creates* a seed. It's then left in place, as there's no storage available for the new item.

If you want to avoid the mess, create some bags at a clothier or leatherworker's work area and your dwarfs will collect the seeds and store them in a food stockpile.

Comment: They are eating and creating seeds? I hope it's because they are simply spitting the seeds out...

Comment: @TimmyJim Dwarves officially (as per the games creator) don't poop. There have been many discussions on this on the games forums. Here is a good place to start if you want to research it more: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=54494.msg1298606#msg1298606

Comment: @TimmyJim If a fruit or vegetable is eaten raw or turned into an alcoholic beverage, the dwarfs take the seeds out first. If the fruit or vegetable is cooked, the seeds are cooked as well and become part of the cooked dish. Ask the game developers how the dwarfs manage to do that with strawberries or mangos.

Comment: @quarague Strawberries are easy, you just need a pair of tweezers and a lot of patience.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Do dwarves have tweezers to use?